# Something to trace http request to and responses from server

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, configuration

We've having a problem at production (IIS + asp.net web forms, a form with devexpress callback panel - kind of a substitute to microsoft's updatepanel), when sometimes server won't respond to a callback - the updatePanel just waits for a response forever.

This occurs from time to time without a stable scenario and we have never encountered such problem on our testing environments.

So, obviously, the reason is something with configuration. I've added some logging and that's what I see:

1. customer reports this 'timeout' (lets call it so) at, say, 12:00
2. I see in logs that a request was received by server and successfully processed in ~0.5sec (i.e. time from page creation to unload)
3. For some reason response did not reach the client.

They say it happens about 8-10 times each working day for each operator. They also say there are no firewalls or other software that may block responses. I'm stuck.

Probably there's an instrument I can ask to install on production environments that will trace and log all http request and responces from server with useful diagnostic information that I can inspect later to see where the blocking occurs?
Pleeeease =))

Comment: You could probably use something like fiddler2 on the client machines to log the traffic, and see what's going on.

Comment: I guess operators won't be able to use it, I need something to set up and collect logs in the evening =)